# Rabbinical violations that are punishable by death?

Tags: halacha, reward-punishment, derabanan, capital-punishment, karet

Are there any rabbinical violations that carry the punishment of kareit (or other death penalty)?

I'm wondering because of [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/54060/1516) answer--which suggests that the prohibition on relations with a non-Jew may be rabbinical--and the discussion [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/51153/from-where-do-we-know-that-sexual-intercourse-with-a-non-jewish-woman-is-forbidd) (especially [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/51219/1516)), which suggests that punishment for this by death is in some cases appropriate.

I am wondering if there are any laws that are truly rabbinical and truly punishable by death? Is such allowed?

Comment: Zaken Mamrei? Technically, the only thing he's doing is contravening the prevailing halachic ruling established by Beis Din. Yes, it's in the Torah, but technically it only exists through a "rabbinical violation..." :)

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky I'm not sure if you're joking but it's actually a major machlokes between the rambam and ramban if there can be a zaken mamre for a din derabanan

Comment: Note, that "punishable by death" and "better to give up one's life before violating" are not the same thing

Comment: Yes Matt, I was joking. :)

Comment: Do you mean categorically punishable by death, or circumstantially?  The Rabbis put people to death for Rabbinical infractions when they saw the need to do such.

Comment: See Gittin 55b that the Gemara assumes as a given fact that kareit is impossible for a Rabbinical law. כרת בדרבנן מי איכא

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The links you provide have to do with giving up one's life to prevent committing a sin. I'll answer according to your question on rabbinical violations that carry a death penalty.

There is a baraita found throughout the Talmud (such as Ber. 4b) which states:

> וכל העובר על דברי חכמים חייב מיתה
>
> Anyone who transgresses the pronouncements of the Sages is liable to
> receive the death penalty

This statement does not mean that the courts can impose the death penalty on people who commit such transgressions. Most commentators understand the baraita as a way of underscoring the seriousness of rabbinical pronouncements, to the extent that one is worthy of  death if transgressing one.

That said, there are no rabbinical laws punishable by *karet*. The list of sins punishable by *karet* can be found in the talmudic tractate devoted to this subject (*Keritot* 2a), and they all derive from the Torah.

There is a potential caveat, however, that deserves mention. The Rambam *appears* to indicate that the courts could strike a sinner to death for transgressing a rabbinic law:

> אסרו חכמים לאכול מצה בערב הפסח כדי שיהיה היכר לאכילתה בערב. ומי שאכל מצה בערב הפסח מכין אותו מכת מרדות **עד שתצא** **נפשו**
>
> The Sages forbade a person from eating matzah on Pesach eve, in order for there to be a distinction between [partaking of it as food] and eating it on the evening [of the fifteen as a mitzvah.] Whoever eats matzah on Pesach eve is given "stripes for rebellion" **until his soul expires**. (Mishneh Torah, Chametz uMatzah 6:12).

Many commentators have used the final clause ("until his soul expires") to understand the extent of rabbinical authority. The Ran, for example, uses Rambam's point to emphasize the first point I mentioned, borrowing language from the Mishnah (San. 11:3):

> ולפי דבריהם יש בזה חומר בדברי סופרים יותר מדברי תורה
>
> These words prove that the law is more severe with respect to the words of the Sages than to the words of the Torah.  (Ran on Rif, *Ketubot* 16b)

It is crucial to note, however, that the most authoritative manuscripts of the Mishneh Torah do not have "until his soul expires" in the text. It is a later addition not from the Rambam, and many contemporary publications of the Mishneh Torah do not include it.

Comment: I was looking for that Rambam last night! (Although the Ohr Somayach says it surely means עד ולא עד בכלל)

Comment: Somewhat related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/20441

Answer (score 1):

The Pri Migadim in Orach Chaim siman 75 Mishbitzos Zahav #2 writes there is misa and kares midivrei sofrim (i.e. rabbinic) for public listening to kol isha of an (even?) unmarried akum.

I don't understand how it could work technically, but he does say it.

[image]