# Can a Gentile say a Bracha before a wedding feast?

Tags: halacha, blessing, gentiles, wedding

If a gentile has been called upon to give the blessing before a wedding meal, with part of the wedding party being Jewish, would there be any problem with including a standard bracha at the end of the prayer, ("baruch atah adonai elokeinu melech haolam" followed by the bracha for wine), where the goal is to make the point that there is one God for all, and to welcome the Jewish participants?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, John and sorry about the icy reception. (I do not believe that the hyper-literal reading about whom the site is intended for is correct. If a martian asks a proper question, it is on-topic regardless of the circumstances surrounding the question. Conflating the intended audience of the site, with a particular question of propriety, is, in my opinion sloppy thinking.) It is true, however, that [intermarriage is strictly forbidden](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/74040/8775) according to Judaism. This certainly overshadows the issue of making a blessing.

Comment: Although it will be difficult to answer this, given the lack of sources about this particular sort of situation, I assume that in a vacuum, there would be no issue with a gentile reciting blessings over food at a public event (although whether the listeners would discharge their obligations to bless, is a separate question.) The matter of emphasizing that it is one God for all, might be [theologically problematic](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/89/8775) depending on which other religion is being compared to Judaism. [cont.]

Comment: [cont.]  This, together with the implicit condonation of the intermarriage, would probably constitute the primary issues.

Comment: @JohnSmith I took the liberty of depersonalizing the question, since the site is not intended for personal guidance. If you want to change it back, or otherwise change it, just [edit](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/76289/edit).

Comment: Adding to @mevaqesh's comment, this would be considered a non-marriage altogether, according to Jewish law. Thus, what would be the purpose of saying a blessing on the wine. You said "before the meal". Does that mean as part of the *chuppah* / sheva brachot, or at the point the guests are sitting down to the meal and he will be making the blessing on wine?

Comment: @DanF You can make a berakha on wine whenever wine is consumed. This is the case whether it not it is a wedding. Furthermore, the OP did not ask whether there would "be a point", but whether there would be a problem.

Comment: @mevaqesh According to many the wine would need to be kosher, the location would need to be clean in certain respects, you can't have alreayd made a blessing which exempts this win, etc.

Comment: @DoubleAA Those requirements apply to non-Jews as well?

Comment: @mevaqesh Perhaps some could (desecrating God's name by saying it around filth, for instance). But that wasn't your claim anyway.

Comment: @mevaqesh You claimed: "You can make a berakha on wine whenever wine is consumed."

Comment: @DoubleAA ah. [15 chars]

Answer (score 2):

Maimonides states that a person is not allowed to answer Amen if a nonJew makes a blessing and it is not considered a valid blessing. In fact, given that the groom is attempting to "marry" a nonJewish woman, one would probably not be allowed to answer Amen if *he* (or another Jew) said the blessing.

[Hilchos Brachos chapter 1](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/927667/jewish/Berachot-Chapter-One.htm) law 13

> 13 Whenever a person hears a Jew recite a blessing, he is obligated to
>   respond Amen, although a) he did not hear the blessing in its
>   entirety, b) he was not obligated to recite that blessing himself.
>
> One should not respond Amen if the person reciting the blessing is a
>   gentile, an apostate, a Samaritan, a child in the midst of study, or
>   an adult who altered the text of the blessing.

The use of the Amen serves to state that the blessing being made is appropriate and valid. The Rambam states in the laws of oaths that a person can be considered to have sworn to the truth of the oath being stated (by another) by answering Amen. Similarly we see in the Torah that a sotah becomes subject to the curse by answering Amen to the oath that a priest reads.

Thus, when a person answers Amen to a blessing he is stating that this is a valid blessing and he is including himself in that blessing (such as now being able to drink the wine or eat the food). If a person is not allowed to answer Amen to a blessing, then the implication would be that it was not a proper bracha.

However, this may not be as simple a question as it seems [Don’t Be So Quick to Respond](http://www.mesora.org/AnsweringAmen2011.html) by [Rabbi Dr. Darrell Ginsberg](http://www.migdalhatorah.org/rdg)

> The concept of a bracha actually has two components to it as it
>   relates to the halachic system. On the one hand, a bracha is a
>   halachic action, a religious performance like any other. The reason a
>   person recites a bracha prior to eating food, for example, is that
>   benefiting from this world requires a matir, so to speak; thus, the
>   bracha is functioning as a halachic performance. As such, a person
>   must be able to relate to this very system in order to recite the
>   bracha. He must be a gavra hamechavein, possessing the inherent
>   ability to have intent prior to engaging in a halachic performance.
>   Based on this reasoning, **one would never answer “Amen” to the bracha
>   of a non-Jew, as he is essentially unable to engage in any Jewish
>   religious performance**.
>
> There is another aspect to bracha that makes it unique, which will aid
>   us in understanding how one could answer “Amen”. The text of a bracha
>   is a statement of objective reality. Within the bracha, a person
>   expresses the fact that God is Blessed, King of the Universe, and
>   relates this idea to the performance at hand, such as referencing God
>   as the “boreh pri ha’adama”. And as we know, the response of “Amen” is
>   in fact an acceptance of this very truth. The Rambam notes that we
>   answer “Amen” even if we are not ourselves obligated in said bracha,
>   indicating that it reflects our acknowledgment of the truth contained
>   in this expression. If this is the case, then the intent of the
>   individual becomes of secondary import. It is true the non-Jew does by
>   definition not have the right intent when making the bracha. However,
>   the cheftzah of bracha is able to emerge regardless, as it stands on
>   its own as a declaration of truth. Therefore, according to this
>   opinion, one should respond “Amen” when (on the off chance) he hears a
>   non-Jew recite the bracha.
>
> In terms of practical pesak, both positions can be found throughout
>   the works of Rishonim and Acharonim. The Tur (OC 215) cites both
>   opinions (his father, the Rosh, following the second line of
>   reasoning). The Shulchan Aruch (ibid 2) only cites the issue as it
>   relates to a kusi; however, he writes in another place (ibid, Beis
>   Yosef) that the kusi is equated to the non-Jew, and therefore we would
>   not answer “Amen” to his bracha. The Rema, however, writes explicitly
>   that one should answer “Amen” to the bracha of the non-Jew.
>
> A more contentious issue emerges in the case of answering “Amen” to
>   the bracha of a kofer/apikoris, an individual who denies a fundamental
>   yesod of Judaism, such as Torah from Sinai, or possesses a distorted
>   idea of God.

He cites Rav Moshe Feinstein as stating that the words of a kofer are actually worse than the blessing recited by a non-Jew and may not be answered at all. This would apply if the (Jewish) groom were asked to recite the blessing.

> R Moshe Feinstein (Igros Moshe OC 2:50, as well as in other teshuvos)
>   expands on this issue, reinforcing that one should not answer “Amen”
>   to a bracha recited by a kofer. He writes, in referring to
>   Conservative/Reform rabbis, that since they are denying God and his
>   Torah, the enunciation of the name of God by them is simply words
>   (devarim be’alma) without any intent towards God. Therefore, it does
>   not even rise to the level of an actual bracha, lacking in shem and
>   malchus.

You should also note that if the groom says the normal statement made at a Jewish wedding (or someone says it for him)

> Behold you are sanctified to me by the laws of Moses and Israel

he is actually stating explicitly that this is not a valid wedding.

Another problem would be if the food (or the wine in this case) is [not kosher](https://www.nishmat.net/torah/view.asp?id=312). There is a dispute between the Rambam (Brachot 1,19) and the Rosh. The Shulchan Aruch (Orach Haim 196,1) rules in line with the Rambam, that one does not say a bracha before or after eating non-kosher food. One should note that the dispute involves whether a Jew (for whom it is a sin) may or may not make a blessing on it.

Note that with wine, this applies even though it was not "*used as a libation for idol worship*" because the laws of libation also apply (by rabbinical decree) to any non-kosher wine.

[Hilchos Brachos chapter 1](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/927667/jewish/Berachot-Chapter-One.htm) law 19

> 19 When a person eats a forbidden food - whether consciously or
>   inadvertently - he should not recite a blessing beforehand or
>   afterward.
>
> What is implied? If one eats tevel - even food that is classified as
>   tevel by Rabbinical decree, the first tithe from which terumah was not
>   separated, or the second tithe or sanctified foods that were not
>   redeemed in the proper manner, one should not recite a blessing.
>   Needless to say, this applies if one ate meat from an animal that was
>   not ritually slaughtered or was trefah or if one drank wine used as a
>   libation for idol worship.

There is a discussion as to the reason behind this dispute which centers on whether the essential meaning of the blessing is centered on whether this is a blessing on a sin (and may even be blasphemous) or that it is valid (after the fact) because there was enjoyment of Hashem's bounty. It is possible that a non-Jew (for whom the food is permitted) would be able to make the blessing, although Jews should not answer Amen.

[Bracha On Non-Kosher Food.](https://www.nishmat.net/torah/view.asp?id=312)

> The Rambam writes "When a person eats a forbidden food - whether
>   bemaizid (intentionally) or beshogeg (inadvertently) - he should not
>   recite a blessing beforehand or afterward" (Brachot 1,19). This is
>   also found in the Talmud Yerushalmi, where it explains that such a
>   blessing would be "na'atz Hashem", as in Tehillim 10,3 which can be
>   read as "the one who blesses and blasphemes Hashem". What a chutzpah
>   to say a bracha on sinful eating!
>
> However, both the Ra'avad and the Rosh rule that a blessing must be
>   said before and after eating non-kosher food. The Mishna merely rules
>   that a non-kosher meal is not considered as important enough to
>   require a zimun on it – but in the words of the Ra'avad, "why
>   shouldn't he say a bracha before and after eating, since he enjoyed
>   the food?"

Comment: `one does not say a bracha before or after eating non-kosher food.` That is totally irrelevant since the OP asked about a **non-Jew** making the blessing. The issue of the poskim is a person making a blessing on a food that is forbidden to him.

Comment: "Maimonides states that a person is not allowed to answer Amen if a nonJew makes a blessing `and it is not considered a valid blessing.`" Where does Rambam say it is not a valid blessing? What does it even mean for a blessing to be "valid"? One would assume that it means that one who says it discharges his obligation. Here that is irrelevant.

Comment: `Therefore, in this case, it would seem that the blessing would not be appropriate.` Why? None of what you cited has any relevance on the case at hand. All we see is that one should not make a blessing on forbidden food, and that at least in some cases, a Jew should not respond 'Amen' to the blessing of a gentile. Neither of these were the OP's question, so this does not answer the question at all.

Comment: @mevaqesh The OP's question was a nonJew making a bracha on what appears to be non-kosher food at a "mixed marriage". (from the original description of what is happening). Thus, both cases cited apply.

Comment: First of all, there was was no indication that any of the food was not kosher. More importantly (besides for other mistakes noted) there is no reason to think (certainly no reason that you provided) that there is any problem whatsoever with a person making a blessing on a food that is permitted for him to consume!

Comment: @mevaqesh The original question seemed to me to imply that the food was not kosher. The last sentence would be a different question. *Can a non-Jew make a bracha on non-kosher food for himself, since it is permitted for him?* The original question was about making the bracha for the groom.

Comment: This is the original text of the question `My daughter is getting married this week, and I have been called upon to giving the blessing before we eat. I would like to include a standard bracha at the end of my prayer, ("baruch atah adonai elokeinu melech haolam" followed by the bracha for wine since I know that will be on the table), since the groom and his family are Jewish I do not believe they are Orthodox or even very religious, but I do want to make the point that there is one God for all, and that my son-in-law is welcome in our family. Would that be OK?` Nothing relevant to your answer.

Comment: @mevaqesh A non-Jew providing the "marriage" of his non-Jewish daughter for a non-religious Jewish man would not be providing kosher food.

Comment: The Rama does not rule like that Rambam https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%98%D7%95_%D7%91

Comment: @sabbahillel We're not here to pasken on a particular real-world case. If you want to make a side point about whether your answer would be different with the added consideration of the wine being non-kosher, fine, but there's certainly no grounds for that consideration to be dispositive of the actual question.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I was pointing out that the fact the the question **as asked** appears to involve non-kosher food does make a difference.

Comment: @sabbahillel We can disagree about whether that aspect could be reasonably inferred, but it's certainly not essential to the question. An answer that is totally predicated on that aspect has sidestepped rather than addressed the actual question.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Note that I start that section with *Another problem*. Thus, I do not totally predicate the answer on that aspect, but point out that the bracha would be inappropriate for that aspect alone. I put the two citations from the Rambam at the end to allow the earlier text to be written and read.

Comment: @sabbahillel Structurally, you are correct. However, the only other part of this answer that addresses the question is the first sentence. I recommend bulking up the first sentence significantly, including a clear citation as well as an explicit explanation of how impermissibility of an "Amen" response implies impropriety of making the blessing in the first place; and bulking down the side-point analysis just as significantly, so that the final product emphasizes a direct, clear response to the question above all else.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I expanded the first part and added why I think that being **forbidden** to answer Amen implies that it is not a valid bracha. I moved the Rambam to the correct location and added why I think that non-kosher food is an issue in this question.