# Who is liable in kol isha and tznius situations?

Tags: halacha, tznius-modesty, kol-isha

If a woman starts singing in a room with men, despite knowing they observe kol isha, is she liable for her voice being heard or are the men that hear her liable?

If a woman dresses non-tznius in front of men, are the men liable for looking, or is the woman liable for dressing that way knowing the situation?

Comment: Liable for what?

Comment: Lfnei e'ver is still there.

Comment: I don't understand the question. They are both doing something wrong!

Comment: @sam http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18135/how-assur-is-mixed-dancing#comment43161_18137

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8402/759

Comment: related [judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18258/1353](http://www.needaneitzah.com/q/103)

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/33293/759

Comment: Would be interested to know whether lifnei iver could ever be a bigger sin than the resulting sin, i.e. kol isha -- or isn't it always?

Comment: @SAH If Lifnei Iveir applies here, it is quite possibly a bigger sin, because Kol Isha is probably Derabanan, while Lifnei Iver is a Deoraita.

Comment: See Benei Banim 3:26

Answer (score 3):

The [Kaf Hachaim 75:23](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14418&st=&pgnum=259) writes that women should be careful not to let their voice be heard in front of men lest the men come to sinful thoughts.

Kaf Hachaim 23 text:

[image]

Regarding the man,Shulchan Aruch Even Haezer 21:1 writes that it is assur to listen to the voice of ervah(a woman's singing voice-per most halachic authorities).

SA text:

**ואסור לשמוע קול ערוה** או לראות שערה. והמתכוין לאחד מאלו הדברים, מכין אותו מכת מרדות. ואלו הדברים אסורים גם בחייבי לאוין.

Comment: In other words, both are liable?

Comment: Men are certainly as per the Shulchan Aruch EH 21,the chiddush is a woman which the Kaf Hachaim holds she should refrain

Comment: Maybe edit that into your answer, so as to answer the question.

Comment: @DannySchoemann where do you see that the woman is liable? The men are the ones having the thoughts, but the woman should be careful. The sinful thoughts are the inherent issur there, not that a woman "let her voice be heard." It certainly COULD be lifnei iver, but curiously the K"H doesn't actually say that here...

Comment: he is saying their voice shouldn't be heard...? lifnei iver is a form of liability

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky - I didn't say either way, I simply asked a question. I just think this is not an answer, unless sam writes something that can be proven, one way or the other.

Answer (score 2):

Both are liable. Think about it: The Talmud considers a woman's voice like her "nakedness" and the same is true about a woman not dressed properly, thus they are both sinning by exposing her nakedness, it would be comparable to a pair who willingly engaged in prohibition relations (for example adultery) whereby both the man and the woman are to be held responsible.

Comment: That sounds a little bit like something the Karites would say.

Comment: Why is that? Please explain yourself.

Comment: You seem to be saying that just like in adultery they are both obligated so too in this case, the common denominator being that both involve uncovering nakedness. This is an extremely literal understanding of the pasuk 'גילה ערותה' and I'm not convinced it's a good pshat at all unless you can source it.

Comment: I hear why it sounds like that it what I meant. I simply meant to prove that just as in regard to all illicit sexual relations both the man and woman are to be held liable for sinning, the same is true in regard to these examples of listening to a woman's singing and looking at a woman not properly dressed.