# What is the source that forbids indecent dress by women?

Tags: halacha, tznius-modesty, mesorah-tradition

I have been hardpressed finding a source for something that would seem to be such a well known Halacha. I (and most other too probably) have been brought up with the belief that it is forbidden for a girl to walk around indecently. What that exactly is depends on whom you ask, with many opinions saying a skirt must reach 4 inches below the knee.

Where does anyone even mention such an Issur in the Torah before 100 years ago?

Here are some Pshatim I have heard.

1. Most people tend to quote the Issur of praying in front of an Ervah, however this is an Issur on Dvorim Shebikdusha and does not dictate how a lady must dress?
2. People bandy about with the term  לִפְנֵ֣י עִוֵּ֔ר לֹ֥א תִתֵּ֖ן מִכְשֹׁ֑ל (Lifnei Iver Loh Siten Michshol). However this should then subject it to the many rules of Lifnei Iver, upon which many leniencies should then apply. For example, one could say there are other ways a man has access to Hirhur and Histaklus, even if those would actually cost him money (Rema 151:1)
3. Another Pshat I heard is that like the Gemoro deduces a woman must cover her hair from the fact it says Uporah Rosh HaIsha, so too we can deduct that she must cover her body because it says you shall uncover her top. This seems to me like a nice Vort, but I dont think we can make Droshos for ourselves.

Is it simply common sense but it was too obvious to be recorded in Halacha? If so, where do the Shiurim of x amount of inches come from? Was it common sense to use the Ervah guidelines used for Dvarim Shebikdusha?

Comment: Re. 3 I don't think we make the Drash. I think it's a Gemara

Comment: I'm 99% convinced it isn't a gemara, but hey, if you can show it to be I'll be thrilled.

Comment: it has to do with erva. what attracts man's attention. dont need pasuk for that

Comment: Pssible dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35151/759

Comment: @ShmuelBrin You're thinking of Sotah 8a. It's not exactly an explicit extenstion to general clothing at all. Plus you still have to explain why no one ever pointed it out till recently.

Comment: @DoubleAA re: the possible dupe, reading that question and accepted answer again, it seems the OP was querying whether a woman's modesty has to with men seeing her or even alone. My question assumes based on universal acceptance that it has to with men seeing her, I just want to know the source.

Comment: Lo tir'eh becha ervas davar?

Comment: http://rabbidovlinzer.blogspot.com/2012/01/torah-from-our-beit-midrash-tzniut.html

Comment: In fact, why should anyone wear clothing at all when outside?

Comment: @DoubleAA are you addressing this comment to anyone in particular? Or is this the start of an answer to the question?

Comment: @Yeh It's the logical extension of your question. I guess you can consider it a suggestion to broaden the scope of your question. This whole discussion is a pretty silly. You wear clothing because it's proper Middos. Women do that too. The way women dressed properly for the last few thousand years is still the appropriate standard and the fact that Lady Gaga walks around naked shouldn't change that. The only reason you see more women having trouble with this nowadays is stores and culture sell them "clothing" that barely deserve the title. I don't know why you're interested in this post.

Comment: @DoubleAA you are saying that there is no Halacha how women should dress and it is only proper Middos. Countless Haredim argue with this assumption (I am not saying I do). I want some kind of source.

Comment: @Yehuda Since when is proper Middos not Halakha??? You are mixing up different connotations of technical terminology to arrive at silly conclusions. That's why I told you this post is silly. Nu nu.

Comment: http://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/1830

Comment: linked one more interesting reference in my answer below, a compilation of sources http://www.rabbimanning.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Hilchot-Tzniut-Part-1.pdf

Comment: http://www.sefaria.org/Tosefta_Berakhot.2.22

Comment: http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/mahshevt/more/c2-2.htm#6

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=14&daf=63b&format=pdf

Comment: @DoubleAA so if tznius is merely proper middos I assume it would then depend on the culture. if a person lived in one of these native tribes that wear little more than a loincloth. Would that be all that's required both for men and women?

Comment: @mroll I never said "merely". Your conclusion isn't the craziest idea.

Comment: @mroll Even if Das Yehudit is binding (which I assume it is as a minhag. Though it's a little too variable maybe to be a minhag.) but even if it is its binding its still changeable so at the minute Hashem gave the Torah people could have  just written loincloths and in the future it's theoretically possible people will wear loincloths.

Answer (score 8):

I still feel the question of "sources for indecent dress by women" deserves a better treatment than we (including me) provided up to now. So let me try again.

In summary

- the key Torah verse prohibits *erva* in the Jewish camp
- the gemara will define a woman's erva as parts of her body, her hair and her voice
- most laws of *tzniut* are part of *dat Yehudit* and differ depending on time and place; all agree that some body parts are erva but the exact limits differ

---

A very relevant source not yet brought up here is a very complete and highly recommended article on *tzniut* by [R Yehuda-Herzl Henkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yehuda_Henkin) in [Tradition 37:3](http://traditionarchive.org/news/_pdfs/Henkin%20QX.1.pdf) [abbreviated RYHH below, page numbers are from the PDF linked and not the printed article].

First R Chaim Tabasky [provides the overall framework](http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=1450)

> In [Devarim 23:15](http://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.23.15?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all) we read that Hashem walks in our (military)
>   camp, and that no matter of nakedness should be seen lest He leaves us.
>   From here we derive the prohibition of nakedness when in Hashem’s
>   presence, e.g., for prayer, Torah study, etc. The term camp, however,
>   implies that a constant restraint is required.

This verse in [Devarim](http://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.23.15?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all) is the source verse given in nearly all discussions of *tzniut* because of its reference to *erva*

> כִּי֩ יְהוָ֨ה אֱלֹהֶ֜יךָ מִתְהַלֵּ֣ךְ ׀ בְּקֶ֣רֶב מַחֲנֶ֗ךָ
>   לְהַצִּֽילְךָ֙ וְלָתֵ֤ת אֹיְבֶ֙יךָ֙ לְפָנֶ֔יךָ וְהָיָ֥ה מַחֲנֶ֖יךָ
>   קָד֑וֹשׁ **וְלֹֽא־יִרְאֶ֤ה בְךָ֙ עֶרְוַ֣ת דָּבָ֔ר** וְשָׁ֖ב מֵאַחֲרֶֽיךָ

"For the Lord your God walks in the midst of your camp, to deliver you, and to give up your enemies before you; therefore your camp shall be holy; **that He sees no unseemly thing [erva] in you**, and turn away from you"

Continues R Chaim Tabasky

> The Rishonim consider the nature of nakedness [erva] and whether the
>   prohibition of uncovering certain parts of the body is fixed or
>   depends on social circumstances. All agree that certain areas of the
>   body fall under the Torah prohibition, while others may be drabanan,
>   or depend on custom.

---

The key gemara on *tzniut* is from [Brakhot 24a](http://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.24a.68?lang=he&layout=block&sidebarLang=all) which defines erva as a woman's *shok* (leg), voice and hair (see RYHH p. 1).

> Rav Hisda said: The calf of a woman's leg is to be regarded as
>   nakedness; as it is said, "Uncover the leg, pass through the rivers"
>   (Is. xlvii. 2) and it continues, "Thy nakedness shall be uncovered,
>   yea, your shame shall be seen" (Is. xlvii. 3).
>   
> Samuel said: a woman's
>   voice is to be regarded as nakedness; as it is said, "For sweet is
>   your voice, and your countenance is comely" (Cant. ii. 14).
>   
> Rav Sheshet
>   said: A woman's hair is to be regarded as nakedness; as it is said,
>   "Your hair is as a flock of goats" (ibid. iv. 1).

Rishonim will debate if the *shok* is above or below the knee, i.e., the thigh or calf. [Rashi](http://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Isaiah.47.2.1-2?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all) on [Isaiah 47:2](http://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.47.2?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all) mentions the arm (*zroa*) as *erva* and *poskim* will similarly debate the extent to which the arm should be covered (see RYHH p. 8).

---

The details of *tzniut* laws vary from time to time and community to community. The notion of differentiating between *dat Moshe* (Torah law) and *dat Yehudit* (custom) in the context of erva comes from [Ktubot 72a-b](http://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.72a.86?lang=he&layout=block&sidebarLang=all) according to many Rishonim (see RYHH p. 12).

> (Mishna) What is dat yehudit? If she goes outside her home with her hair
>   uncovered.
>
> (Gemara) Going out with her hair uncovered is a Biblical
>   prohibition for it is written "he shall uncover the head of the
>   woman". And a Tanna in the academy of R Yishmael taught "This is a
>   warning to Jewish daughters that they should not go out with their
>   head uncovered".
>
> Biblically it is sufficient to cover her hair with her
>   head-basket [which allows hair to show through] But in accordance to
>   *dat yehudit* it is prohibited for her even to go out with her head-based [rather a more thorough covering is required]
>   (translation Artscroll)

Indeed the Shulchan Aruch ([OC 75:1](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayyim.75?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all), [EH 73:1](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.73?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all)) doesn't detail the specific laws of *tzniut* but refers to local practices and local places. See also [Mishna Brura 75:2](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.75?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all).

Interestingly in some cases, *tzniut* customs have become **less** constraining in recent times, see e.g., Rambam in [Hilkhot Ishut 13:11](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/952887/jewish/Ishut-Chapter-Thirteen.htm) where he notes women of his time used to go to the market with a veil covering their entire body!

[R Michael Broyde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Broyde) wrote [an entire monography](http://traditionarchive.org/news/_pdfs/0095-0180.pdf) to elucidate whether the obligation of covering a woman's hair was a Torah or rabbinic commandment and concludes

> I have set out to investigate this topic in the footsteps of the great
>   decisors, and I tried to search all the books I could find to gather
>   the views of the Rishonim on hair covering for women, and I have
>   discovered that many of them — Tosafot, Rosh, the Tur, and Terumat
>   Ha-Deshen in particular — established the prohibition for a woman to
>   go with her head uncovered as a violation of **dat yehudit and a
>   subjective rabbinic prohibition.**

Comment: Doesn’t point 1 in the question preempt “the key gemara”?

Answer (score 1):

Well, for a start, the Gemara in Shabbat 62b brings the following as a reason for personal punishment on the subject of the pesukim mentioned as well as contributing to the reasons for the destruction of Jerusalem:

> דרש רבא בריה דרב עילאי: מאי דכתיב ויאמר ה' יען כי גבהו בנות ציון
>   ? שהיו מהלכות בקומה זקופה, ותלכנה נטויות גרון שהיו מהלכות עקב בצד
>   גודל, ומשקרות עינים דהוה מלאן כוחלא לעינייהו ומרמזן, הלוך וטפוף שהיו
>   מהלכות ארוכה בצד קצרה, וברגליהן תעכסנה, אמר רב יצחק דבי רבי אמי: מלמד
>   שמטילות מור ואפרסמון במנעליהן, ומהלכות בשוקי ירושלים, וכיון שמגיעות
>   אצל בחורי ישראל, בועטות בקרקע ומתיזות עליהם ומכניסות בהן יצר הרע כארס
>   בכעוס וכו'.

So bottom line I think that the blame for "מכניסות בהן יצר הרע כארס" implies that the reason is indeed "לפני עור לא תתן מכשול".

Answer (score 1):

This is a very interesting and basic question that, for some reason, didn't get a proper answer. So let me try.

This [other answer on MY](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8402/is-modesty-a-positive-or-negative-commandment) partially answers and lists four sources for the concept of *tzniut* (modesty)

1. > וְהֶעֱמִ֨יד הַכֹּהֵ֥ן אֶֽת־הָאִשָּׁה֮ לִפְנֵ֣י יְהוָה֒ וּפָרַע֙
   >   אֶת־רֹ֣אשׁ הָֽאִשָּׁ֔ה

   "And the Kohen shall set the woman before God, and let the hair of the woman’s head go loose" ([Bamidbar 5:18](http://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.5.18?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all)) (from which the gemara at the end of Ketubot 72a learns that women need to cover their hair)
2. > וְלֹֽא־תָתֻ֜רוּ אַחֲרֵ֤י לְבַבְכֶם֙ וְאַחֲרֵ֣י עֵֽינֵיכֶ֔ם
   >   אֲשֶׁר־אַתֶּ֥ם זֹנִ֖ים אַחֲרֵיהֶֽם

   "Don't stray after your eyes" ([Bamidbar 15:39](http://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.15.39?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all))
3. > קְדֹשִׁ֣ים תִּהְי֑וּ כִּ֣י קָד֔וֹשׁ אֲנִ֖י יְהוָ֥ה אֱלֹהֵיכֶֽם

   "You shall be holy for I the Lord your God am holy" ([Vayikra 19:2](http://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.19.2?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all))
   (adds [Rashi](http://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Leviticus.19.2.2?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all) "by keeping yourselves far away from sinful thoughts and forbidden relations")
4. > וּמָֽה־יְהוָ֞ה דּוֹרֵ֣שׁ מִמְּךָ֗ כִּ֣י אִם־עֲשׂ֤וֹת מִשְׁפָּט֙
   >   וְאַ֣הֲבַת חֶ֔סֶד וְהַצְנֵ֥עַ לֶ֖כֶת עִם־אֱלֹהֶֽיךָ

   "And what does God require of you: Only to do justice, to love mercy and to walk humbly with your God" ([Micah 6:8](http://www.sefaria.org/Micah.6.8?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all))

But only the first of these sources really applies to women. The others are injunctions on men -- and women's tzniut might only be there to help men not stumble.

**I found three other sources that create a basis for women's tzniut**

5. > וַתֹּ֣אמֶר אֶל־הָעֶ֗בֶד מִֽי־הָאִ֤ישׁ הַלָּזֶה֙ הַהֹלֵ֤ךְ בַּשָּׂדֶה֙ לִקְרָאתֵ֔נוּ וַיֹּ֥אמֶר הָעֶ֖בֶד ה֣וּא אֲדֹנִ֑י
   >   וַתִּקַּ֥ח הַצָּעִ֖יף וַתִּתְכָּֽס

   Rivka covering herself when seeing her future husband Yitzhak ([Bereshit 24:65](http://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.24.65?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all))
6. > כָּל־כְּבוּדָּ֣ה בַת־מֶ֣לֶךְ פְּנִ֑ימָה

   "All glory of the King's daughter is within" ([Tehilim 45:14](http://All%20glorious%20is%20the%20king's%20daughter%20within%20the%20palace))
7. > כִּי֩ יְהוָ֨ה אֱלֹהֶ֜יךָ מִתְהַלֵּ֣ךְ ׀ בְּקֶ֣רֶב מַחֲנֶ֗ךָ לְהַצִּֽילְךָ֙ וְלָתֵ֤ת אֹיְבֶ֙יךָ֙ לְפָנֶ֔יךָ וְהָיָ֥ה מַחֲנֶ֖יךָ קָד֑וֹשׁ וְלֹֽא־יִרְאֶ֤ה בְךָ֙ עֶרְוַ֣ת דָּבָ֔ר וְשָׁ֖ב מֵאַחֲרֶֽיךָ

   "For the Lord your God walks in the midst of your camp, to deliver you, and to give up your enemies before you; therefore your camp shall be holy; that He sees no unseemly thing in you, and turn away from you" ([Devarim 23:15](http://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.23.15?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all))

   [Writes R Chaim Tabasky](http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=1450) on this verse

   > From here we derive the prohibition of nakedness when in Hashem’s
   >   presence, e.g. for prayer, Torah study, etc. The term camp, however,
   >   implies that a constant restraint is required. The Rishonim consider
   >   the nature of nakedness (ervah) and whether the prohibition of
   >   uncovering certain parts of the body is fixed or depends on social
   >   circumstances. All agree that certain areas of the body fall under the
   >   Torah prohibition, while others may be drabanan, or depend on custom.

---

On the derivation of some of the *halachot* of *tzniut* from Torah sources, see for instance R Mordechai Willig [here](http://www.torahweb.org/torah/2010/parsha/rwil_bamidbar.html)

> Notwithstanding the immutability of the Torah's principle of modesty
>   and its particular application to women, the precise details are
>   subject to communal standards which often change and/or vary from
>   place to place. This is true regarding some parts of a woman's body
>   which must be covered (Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 75:1). Nonetheless,
>   there are other parts which must be covered regardless of communal
>   standards.
>
> The Mishna Brura draws the line at the elbow and the knee (75:2). Some
>   interpret "shok" (Berachos 24a) as the calf (since the thigh is called
>   yerech), and include it in objective erva (see Chazon Ish Orach Chaim
>   16:8). Yet others imply that since the requirement to cover the arms
>   and legs is das Yehudis (Kesubos 72a), i.e. a custom of Jewish women
>   (Rashi), it may be subject to change (see Kaf Hachayim 75:2, Igros
>   Moshe Even Hoezer 1:69). Sha'ar Hatziyun 75:5 disagrees.
>
> However, a woman's torso is certainly ervah (see Rambam Krias Shma
>   3:16), and must be covered. Unfortunately, many otherwise observant
>   women follow fashions, such as very low necklines, which expose the
>   flesh inappropriately. Women who wear tight-fitting clothes which
>   explicitly delineate a woman's figure are also in violation, as the
>   Midrash, contrasting Rus and the other women, implies (see Kuntres
>   Dinei Malbush Nashim page 12, 13).

---

See also [here](http://www.rabbimanning.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Hilchot-Tzniut-Part-1.pdf) and [here](http://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/modesty-tzniut/#) for further sources.

Comment: 1. Only applies to married women acc. to halacha

Comment: 2. 3. 4.: you've rebuffed them yourself and again - no explicit referencing to causing attraction done by women. 5. was only a display of bashfulness in front of future husband - otherwise would have done it on meeting Eliezer and his men. 6. just says it's a statement of nobility to be more hidden - doesn't answer the question - a source that "it's forbidden for a girl to walk around indecently". 7. if you can bring a chazal that it refers to women's modesty then fine but as it stands, the pshat refers to doing one's needs.

Comment: @nzn I actually never thought about what you just said, your comment hear can be used to further refute point 3 in my question that this Posuk refers to married women.

Comment: @nzn a similar pasuk (כי מצא בה ערות דבר) was discussed in Daf Yomi just the other day, end of Gittin: ראשה פרוע וטווה בשוק ופרומה משני צדדיה ורוחצת עם בני אדם is, a couple of lines further down, called a רשעה.

Answer (score 1):

1. R. Moshe Shmuel Glasner, Dor Revi'i (peticha, no. 2) explains that there are things which are not expressly prohibited by the Torah but which are considered more severe than explicit Torah prohibitions. His first example of this is public nudity:

> ועוד תדע דבכל דברים המאוסים שנפשו של אדם קצה בהם, אפילו לא היה התורה
>   אוסרתן, היה האדם העובר ואוכלן יותר מתועב ממי שעובר על לאו מפורש בתורה, כי
>   כל מה שנתקבל בעיני בני אדם הנאורים לתועבה אפילו אינו מפורש בתורה
>   לאיסור, העובר ע"ז גרע מן העובר על חוקי התורה. למשל, התורה אמרה לא ילבש
>   גבר שמלת אשה, אבל **שלא לילך ערום בשוק לא איפרש בתורה שהוא אסור, אבל הוא
>   נימוס וחוק קבוע אצל כל בעלי דעה**... ועתה אשאלך מי שקץ משנתו ומושכב ערום במטתו, והבית בוער באש עד שמוכרח להמלט על נפשו ולרוץ החוצה ואין לפניו רק שמלת אשה לכסות ערומיו... בעיני פשוט הדבר דלצאת ערום עבירה יותר גדולה מלבישת בגד אשה, כי היא עבירה המוסכמת אצל כל בעלי דעה, והעובר עליה יצא מכלל אדם הנברא בצלם אלקים.

In other words, he says that nudity is nowhere prohibited in the Torah--however, it is nevertheless more severe than actual Torah prohibitions because it violates  a universal standard of morality.

2. The rosh yeshiva of the "open orthodox" yeshiva YCT, Dov Linzer, wrote an [article in the New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/01/20/opinion/ultra-orthodox-jews-and-the-modesty-fight.html) a few years ago claiming that demanding women dress modestly is a "blame-the-victim mentality." According to Linzer, "The Talmud tells the religious man, in effect: If you have a problem, you deal with it." He explained his reasoning in a [blog post](http://www.rabbidovlinzer.blogspot.com/2012/01/torah-from-our-beit-midrash-tzniut.html). In short, halakhic sources define "*ervah*" but focus on the prohibition of reciting *devarim shebikdusha* in the presence of *ervah*. However, in light of the Dor Revi'i's aforementioned view, perhaps once halakha defines *ervah*, whatever is considered *ervah* falls under the category of a logical prohibition.
3. See also this [article in Hama'ayan](http://www.machonso.org/uploads/images/215-11%2069-78.pdf) which discusses the issue.

Comment: @mevaqesh what are the dogmatic reasons?

Comment: Well they didn't comment, but I guessed it had to do with any reference to Open Orthodox. It seems that people often vote based on the names they see rather than the actual content of the answer. If they see unpopular names, they downvote.

Comment: @mevaqesh I see what you're saying

Comment: The *Dor R'vi'i* seems to have been talking about a man going in public without any clothes, not a woman.

Comment: @Fred you think it's a mitzvas aseh shehazman grama?

Comment: @wfb Not sure if you're joking, but I wasn't saying that only men should refrain from wearing no clothes in public. I was saying that there are presumably other halachic considerations for why women should **not** appear in public unclothed, in addition to just `because it's obviously a bad thing to do`, which is the only reason the *Dor R'vi'i* gives for why men shouldn't do it. In other words, the *Dor R'vi'i* doesn't support the claim in your answer that `nudity is nowhere prohibited in the Torah` for women.

Answer (score 1):

it is indeed not so "clear cut". here is a halachic discussion from Rabbi Mordechai Willig which sheds light on this

> Notwithstanding the immutability of the Torah's principle of modesty
> and its particular application to women, the precise details are
> subject to communal standards which often change and/or vary from
> place to place. This is true regarding some parts of a woman's body
> which must be covered (Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 75:1). Nonetheless,
> there are other parts which must be covered regardless of communal
> standards.
>
> The Mishna Brura draws the line at the elbow and the knee (75:2). Some
> interpret "shok" (Berachos 24a) as the calf (since the thigh is called
> yerech), and include it in objective erva (see Chazon Ish Orach Chaim
> 16:8). Yet others imply that since the requirement to cover the arms
> and legs is das Yehudis (Kesubos 72a), i.e. a custom of Jewish women
> (Rashi), it may be subject to change (see Kaf Hachayim 75:2, Igros
> Moshe Even Hoezer 1:69). Sha'ar Hatziyun 75:5 disagrees.
>
> However, a woman's torso is certainly ervah (see Rambam Krias Shma
> 3:16), and must be covered. Unfortunately, many otherwise observant
> women follow fashions, such as very low necklines, which expose the
> flesh inappropriately. Women who wear tight-fitting clothes which
> explicitly delineate a woman's figure are also in violation, as the
> Midrash, contrasting Rus and the other women, implies (see Kuntres
> Dinei Malbush Nashim page 12, 13).
>
> The distinction between variable details and timeless principles is
> not limited to dress. It applies, in a more complex and nuanced way,
> to the definition of tznius in the Torah society. For example, public
> speaking by a woman in front of mixed audiences is commonplace in some
> circles and unheard of in others. For many parts of Torah society, it
> depends upon the place, the occasion, and other factors. Similarly,
> interaction between men and women, another subject of the Midrash
> about Rus, is also dependent upon local custom (Beis Shmuel 62:11, see
> Otzar Haposkim there). This includes separate seating, entrances,
> mechitzos, etc. Here, too, context is clearly critical.
>
> It must be noted that the opposite of tznius is pritzus (Kesubos 3b),
> a term linked to one who breaks a fence (Koheles 10:8), and different
> communities legitimately build their fences in different places. As
> such, a garment, speech, or event can be labeled as pritzus in one
> place, but be acceptable in another.

from http://www.torahweb.org/torah/2010/parsha/rwil_bamidbar.html

Comment: Isnt this already quoted in mbloch's answer?

Comment: @DoubleAA ah yes. didnt see that part. i think it's the main point though and the quote is longer. so will leave.